# How to reactivate a trigger after enable it

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I want to reactivate a trigger after enable it but I don't find any solution to my problem. I work on postgresql database.

I used the following command to enable my trigger logmodif_contact

`ALTER TABLE contact_sas enable TRIGGER logmodif_contact`;

After that I use the command that throw me true to indicate the trigger is enabled.

```
    SELECT  tgenabled
    FROM    pg_trigger
    WHERE   tgname='logmodif_contact' AND
            tgenabled != 'D'
);
```

And now the trigger is enabled I can do my work but after that I must reactivate it to insure the database integrity.

Comment: 1) `enable` = `activated` so there is no reactivation to be done. The process is `disable TRIGGER` to deactivate it and then `enable TRIGGER` to activate it.  2) Why the `MySQL` tag?

Comment: Ok sorry I thought that enable meant desactivate, i must improve my englisk I think... Thank you !